# What to do about poor quality answers?

Tags: discussion, flagging, answer-quality

I recently [asked a question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/304920/what-are-methods-for-recovering-a-linux-kernel-config) and spent a long time wordsmithing it before submitting.  The entire idea was to demonstrate that there were many things I had checked and save time from people suggesting those answers.

The problem is I keep getting answers which show people are not even reading the original question.  What is the correct thing to do here?  I'm commenting on each one individually but there isn't a "flag" option of "didn't bother to read the question" and thus I don't *think* flagging is the right answer.  Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Downvoting is the correct response.

Comment: Yes downvoting is what you're suppose to do and also leaving a comment to that effect.

Comment: @john no it won't and please don't do that! Mod flags should only be used for things that require mod intervention. Unhelpful answers should just be downvoted.

Comment: @terdon, but if it's *actually* not an answer to the question asked, it could be flagged as "not an answer."

Comment: @Wildcard yes, but not a custom mod flag to let us know the user put no effort into their answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go and downvote the answer along with a comment, to educate the user. In addition to that, I would also flag the question as "Very Low Quality" if it is really that bad.

This way community knows about the questions poor state and with the flagging others, with responsability are being informed of it.